# Extracting "unsigned files" from a directory

Tags: python, directory, python-2.x

I have a directory with xml files associated with encrypted P7M files, meaning that for every name.xml there is a name.P7M. But there are some exceptions (P7M file is absent) and my goal is to detect them using python.

I'm thinking this code.. Can you help with an elegant code?

```
import glob

# functions to eleminate extension name
def is_xml(x):
  a =  re.search(r"(\s)(.xml)",x)
  if a :
    return a.group(0)
  else:
    return False


def is_P7M(x):
  a =  re.search(r"(\s)(.P7M)", x)
  if a :
    return a.group(0)
  else:
    return False

# putting xml files and P7M files in two sets
setA = set (glob.glob('directory/*.xml'))
setB = set (glob.glob('directory/*.P7M')) 


#eliminating extention names
for elt in setA:
   elt= is_xml(elt)

for elt in setB:
  elt= is_P7M(elt)


#difference between two sets. setB is always a larger set
print "unsigned files are:", setB.difference(setA)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way is to glob for the `.xml` files, then check using `os.path.exists` for a `.P7M` file:

```
import os, glob

for xmlfile in glob.glob('*.xml'):
    if not os.path.exists(xmlfile.rsplit(".", 1)[0] + ".P7M"):
        print xmlfile, "is unsigned"
```

This code:

1. Uses `glob.glob` to get all the xml files.
2. Uses `str.rsplit` to split the filename up into name and extension (e.g. `"name.xml"` to `("name", ".xml")`). The second argument stops `str.rsplit` splitting more than once.
3. Takes the name of the file and adds the `.P7M` extension.
4. Uses `os.path.exists` to see if the key file is there. If is isn't, the xmlfile is unsigned, so print it out.

If you need them in a list, you can do:

```
unsigned = [xmlfile for xmlfile in glob.glob('*.xml') if not os.path.exists(xmlfile.rsplit(".", 1)[0] + ".P7M")]
```

Or a set:

```
unsigned = {xmlfile for xmlfile in glob.glob('*.xml') if not os.path.exists(xmlfile.rsplit(".", 1)[0] + ".P7M")}
```

Answer (score 1):

get all xml's in a dict removing the extension and using the name as key and setting the value to false initially, if we find a matching P7M set value to True, finally print all keys with a False value.

```
xmls = glob.glob('directory/*.xml')
p7ms = glob.glob('directory/*.P7M')
# use xml file names as keys by removing the extension
d = {k[rsplit(k,1)[0]]:False for k in xmls}

# go over every .P7M again removing extension
# setting value to True for every match
for k in p7ms:
    k[rsplit(k,1)[0]] = True

# any values that are False means there is no .P7M match for the xml file
for k,v in d.items():
    if not v:
        print(k)
```

Or create a set of each and find the difference:

```
xmls = {x.rsplit(".",1)[0] for x in  in glob.glob('directory/*.xml')}
pm7s = {x.rsplit(".",1)[0] for x  in glob.glob('directory/*.P7M')}

print(xmls - pm7s)
```

Comment: can you explain with some comments please ?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over `glob` once and populate a dict of filenames by extension. Finally, compute the difference between 'xml' and 'P7M' sets.

```
import os, glob, collections

fnames = collections.defaultdict(set)

for fname in glob.glob('*'):
    f, e = os.path.splitext(fname)
    fnames[e].add(f)

print fnames['.xml'] - fnames['.P7M']
```

Note that unlike other suggestions, this makes one single request to the filesystem, which might be important if the FS is slow (e.g. a network mount).

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be:

```
import glob
import os

get_name = lambda fname: os.path.splitext(fname)[0]
xml_names = {get_name(fname) for fname in glob.glob('directory/*.xml')}
p7m_names = {get_name(fname) for fname in glob.glob('directory/*.p7m')}
unsigned = [xml_name + ".xml" for xml_name in \
    xml_names.difference(p7m_names)]

print unsigned
```